# can't use href="#id" when there's a js script

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

i added a chart using chartjs library but now for some reason my text which have a href link that can take the user to specific section of my website is not working anymore.

```
<li><a href="#records">Records</a></li>
<li><a href="#streams">Data</a></li>
<li><a href="#billion">Club</a></li>
```

like above code is not taking me to the id section of those and when i'm removing chart script code (chartjs) then it's working fine.

here's the script code of the chart which causing this problem

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Streams (millions)",
        backgroundColor: ["#D6CC70", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850", "#3e95cd"],
        data: [738,633,678,770,681,660]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: { display: false },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: '2022'
    }
  }
  });
```

Comment: Do you have a reproducable example of this? Cant get it to reproduce, official docs do have charts and links and both work fine

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, I suggest you to take a minute to read [how to create a mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Moreover, could you give an example of the not working code?